# How do I make an R shiny application from Census Data by creating graphs of it as scatterplots, map, timeseries?

Tags: r, shiny

I am building an R shiny application by taking data from Census API  and creating a side-by-side visualization with different variables. 
How can I create these graphs by pulling data from Census API in my 
shiny application.
I have tried to create code by creating graphs but it is not working 
out. Also, how can I make these graphs very pretty and colorful

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(leaflet)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidycensus)
library(censusapi)
library(stringr)
library(RCurl)


#API
Sys.setenv(CENSUS_KEY = "XXXXXXXXX")
# Reload .Renviron
readRenviron("~/.Renviron")
# Check to see that the expected key is output in your R console
Sys.getenv("CENSUS_KEY")
v17 <- load_variables(2017, "acs5", cache = TRUE)
census_api_key("xxxxxxx", overwrite 
= FALSE, install = FALSE)

# data prepare before using in shinapp

This code is there to help with the shinyapp and explain its 
significant for the tract data 

num = get_acs(geography = "tract", 
              state = "06",
              county = "075",
              variables = "B07013_001",
              geometry = TRUE)
```

I should have two graphs side-by-side and people should select 
categories from them and then it should display various results.

Comment: Your questions is very broad and contains at least two issues. Maybe start [here](https://walkerke.github.io/tidycensus/articles/basic-usage.html) and check the general tutorials for shiny [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/). BTW you also posted your 'personal' census API key.

Comment: I think what I am trying to ask is that I need to know how to code that, so could you code it for me. I would be willing to pay you for it. Paypal, Venmo, etc, im down to do it.